# Grizzly 2.2.19 SSL sample code not working

Tags: java, ssl, grizzly

Very little documentation, above what exists in the sample code is currently available for Grizzly 2.2 and I have found this to be most difficult to navigate as it relates to SSL implementation. I am desperately in need of some guidance in this area. After reviewing my code to determine what I need to post in order to pose a complete question, I realized it might be most beneficial to first cement the basics.

Below are three classes provided by the [Grizzly project](http://grizzly.java.net/) in order to demonstrate a sample implementation of Grizzly's SSL capabilities. Besides the removal of comments, the code is identical to the 2.2.19 released code base as maintained in git at **git://java.net/grizzly~git** and also available [here](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/grizzly/samples/grizzly-framework-samples/2.2.19/grizzly-framework-samples-2.2.19-sources.jar).

***The git repository also provides the referenced truststore and keystore.***

#### EchoFilter:

```
public class EchoFilter extends BaseFilter{
    @Override
    public NextAction handleRead(FilterChainContext ctx)throws IOException {
        //|Peer address is used for non-connected UDP Connection
        final Object peerAddress = ctx.getAddress();
        final Object message = ctx.getMessage();
        ctx.write(peerAddress, message, null);
        return ctx.getStopAction();
    }
}
```

#### SSLEchoServer:

```
public class SSLEchoServer{
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int PORT = 7777;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //|Create a FilterChain using FilterChainBuilder
        FilterChainBuilder filterChainBuilder = FilterChainBuilder.stateless();
        //|Add TransportFilter, which is responsible for reading and writing data to the connection
        filterChainBuilder.add(new TransportFilter());

        //|Initialize and add SSLFilter
        final SSLEngineConfigurator serverConfig = initializeSSL();
        final SSLEngineConfigurator clientConfig = serverConfig.copy().setClientMode(true);

        filterChainBuilder.add(new SSLFilter(serverConfig, clientConfig));

        //|Add StringFilter, which will be responsible for Buffer <-> String transformation
        filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        //|Use the plain EchoFilter
        filterChainBuilder.add(new EchoFilter());

        //|Create TCP transport
        final TCPNIOTransport transport = TCPNIOTransportBuilder.newInstance().build();

        //|Set filterchain as a Transport Processor
        transport.setProcessor(filterChainBuilder.build());

        try{
            //|Binding transport to start listen on certain host and port
            transport.bind(HOST, PORT);
            //|Start the transport
            transport.start();
            System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server...");
            System.in.read();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Stopping transport...");
            //|Stop the transport
            transport.stop();
            System.out.println("Stopped transport...");
        }
    }

    private static SSLEngineConfigurator initializeSSL(){
        //|Initialize SSLContext configuration
        SSLContextConfigurator sslContextConfig = new SSLContextConfigurator();

        //|Set key store
        ClassLoader cl = SSLEchoServer.class.getClassLoader();
        URL cacertsUrl = cl.getResource("ssltest-cacerts.jks");
        if(cacertsUrl != null){
            sslContextConfig.setTrustStoreFile(cacertsUrl.getFile());
            sslContextConfig.setTrustStorePass("changeit");
        }

        //|Set trust store
        URL keystoreUrl = cl.getResource("ssltest-keystore.jks");
        if(keystoreUrl != null){
            sslContextConfig.setKeyStoreFile(keystoreUrl.getFile());
            sslContextConfig.setKeyStorePass("changeit");
        }

        //|Create SSLEngine configurator
        return new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContextConfig.createSSLContext(), false, false, false);
    }
}
```

#### SSLEchoClient:

```
public class SSLEchoClient{
    private static final String MESSAGE = "Hello World!";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //|Create a FilterChain using FilterChainBuilder
        FilterChainBuilder filterChainBuilder = FilterChainBuilder.stateless();

        //|Add TransportFilter, which is responsible for reading and writing data to the connection
        filterChainBuilder.add(new TransportFilter());

        //|Initialize and add SSLFilter
        final SSLEngineConfigurator serverConfig = initializeSSL();
        final SSLEngineConfigurator clientConfig = serverConfig.copy().setClientMode(true);

        final SSLFilter sslFilter = new SSLFilter(serverConfig, clientConfig);
        filterChainBuilder.add(sslFilter);

        //|Add StringFilter, which will be responsible for Buffer <-> String transformation
        filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        //|Add Filter, which will send a greeting message and check the result
        filterChainBuilder.add(new SendMessageFilter(sslFilter));

        //|Create TCP transport
        final TCPNIOTransport transport = TCPNIOTransportBuilder.newInstance().build();

        //|Set filterchain as a Transport Processor
        transport.setProcessor(filterChainBuilder.build());

        try{
            //|Start the transport
            transport.start();
            //|Perform async. connect to the server
            transport.connect(SSLEchoServer.HOST, SSLEchoServer.PORT);
            System.out.println("Press any key to stop the client...");
            System.in.read();
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Stopping transport...");
            //|Stop the transport
            transport.stop();
            System.out.println("Stopped transport...");
        }
    }

    private static class SendMessageFilter extends BaseFilter{
        private final SSLFilter sslFilter;

        public SendMessageFilter(SSLFilter sslFilter){
            this.sslFilter = sslFilter;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public NextAction handleConnect(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException{
            final Connection connection = ctx.getConnection();

            //|Execute async SSL handshake
            sslFilter.handshake(connection, new EmptyCompletionHandler<SSLEngine>(){

                //|Once SSL handshake will be completed - send greeting message
                @Override
                public void completed(SSLEngine result){
                    //|Here we send String directly
                    connection.write(MESSAGE);
                }
            });

            return ctx.getInvokeAction();
        }

        @Override
        public NextAction handleRead(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException{
            //|The received message is String
            final String message = (String) ctx.getMessage();

            //|Check the message
            if(MESSAGE.equals(message)){
                System.out.println("Got echo message: \"" + message + "\"");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Got unexpected echo message: \"" + message + "\"");
            }

            return ctx.getStopAction();
        }
    }

    private static SSLEngineConfigurator initializeSSL(){
        //|Initialize SSLContext configuration
        SSLContextConfigurator sslContextConfig = new SSLContextConfigurator();

        //|Set key store
        ClassLoader cl = SSLEchoClient.class.getClassLoader();
        URL cacertsUrl = cl.getResource("ssltest-cacerts.jks");
        if(cacertsUrl != null){
            sslContextConfig.setTrustStoreFile(cacertsUrl.getFile());
            sslContextConfig.setTrustStorePass("changeit");
        }

        //|Set trust store
        URL keystoreUrl = cl.getResource("ssltest-keystore.jks");
        if(keystoreUrl != null){
            sslContextConfig.setKeyStoreFile(keystoreUrl.getFile());
            sslContextConfig.setKeyStorePass("changeit");
        }

        //|Create SSLEngine configurator
        return new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContextConfig.createSSLContext(), false, false, false);
    }
}
```

#### When executing:

*Run SSLEchoServer:*

> Press any key to stop the server...

*Run SSLEchoClient:*

> Press any key to stop the client...

#### Question:

What is this code supposed to accomplish or demonstrate? Beyond the console output you see above, this code does nothing on my end.

In reviewing the code, my expectation was that the client was supposed start its TCP transport and connect it to the server. In the process of that connection being made, the *SendMessageFilter* previously added to the filter stream will execute its *handleConnect()* method, which I confirmed does execute. But, this code never executes the *connection.write(MESSAGE)* statement.

It's clear the intention here is to execute the *write()* method after the handshake thread completes, but it doesn't appear to do so, and in examining the *handshake()* method in SSLFilter class in [grizzly-framework-2.2.19](http://www.versioneye.com/package/org~glassfish~grizzly--grizzly-framework/version/2~2~19), I was also unable to determine where the overridden parent *completed()* method is even defined.

Can anyone lend some insight to whether this disconnect is due to my lack of understanding something here or if it is potentially a bug in the sample implementation provided by Grizzly? I believe clearing this up will go a long way to further my understanding here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The point of the example is to demonstrate basic SSL functionality within Grizzly.  It's odd that this sample doesn't work for you (and you do understand what it's supposed to do).  I've run the same version here and it works fine.  It may be best to take this discussion to the Grizzly User's list for further investigation.  Once nailed down, we can follow up here for the wider audience.